# How to position watermark on right side in Imagick PHP?

Tags: php, imagick

How to position watermark label on right side in bottom? I use **Imagick** php functions.

```
$image->compositeImage($watermark, imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 20, 20);
```

What param I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

[Full explenation](http://holamundo.blog.com/2011/07/31/creating-watermarks-and-image-compositions-with-php-and-imagick/)

```
// Calculate coordinates of top left corner
// of the sprite inside of the image
// "- 10" stands for offset to image border
$left = $imageWidth - $spriteWidth - 10;
$top = $imageHeight - $spriteHeight - 10;

$image->compositeImage($sprite,
        Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT,
        $left, $top);
```